# For an arbitrary ring $R$ and a positive integer $n >1$, are the category of $R$-modules and the category of $M_n(R)$-modules isomorphic?

Tags: category-theory

For an arbitrary ring $R$ and a positive integer $n >1$, are the category of $R$-modules and the category of $M_n(R)$-modules isomorphic?

Here, $M_n(R)$ denotes the $n\times n$ matrices over the ring $R$.

I know these two categories are equivalent, and I guess they are not necessarily isomorphic, but I don't know how to prove it...

Many thanks :)

Comment: Why would you want to know? Just curiosity? Isomorphism of categories is usually too strong a property; that's why equivalence of categories is more prevalent, as it is normally just as useful but easier to handle.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to comment. I want to know about this not just for curiosity. This a problem in Basic Algebra written by Nanthan Jacobson.

Comment: Then *say so in your question*. It's called "giving context".

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your set theoretic assumptions.

The thing is : they're equivalent, and every isomorphism class is a proper class, actually you can "measure it" : every isomorphism class has the same size as the universe.

So if you allow a strong enough axiom of choice (on proper classes), then they're isomorphic : simply biject each isomorphism class and build the isomorphism that way (using a skeleton if that makes things easier).

More generally (still under a strong enough axiom of choice), if $F: C\to D$ is an equivalence of categories such that for each $c\in C$, the isomorphism class of $c$ is bijective with that of $F(c)$, then there is an isomorphism $C\to D$ (it's not $F$ in general though !)

I can detail the proof if you want.

I don't know what happens if you remove the axiom of choice, maybe there's a slick isomorphism between the two.